# Cannot correctly execute GDB

Tags: gdb

First of all sorry for my ignorance, I am just starting in the hacking world and I am feeling a bit lost. I am trying to use gdb to debug a simple program in an Ubuntu machine. After executing said program (backtoshell) I try attaching it to gdb using the command "sudo gdb attach -p (process code)", and supposedly this should appear:
[supposed result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6h5T.png)
[supposed result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcCFm.png)

But instead, seems like pwngdb doesnt execute correctly and only this appears:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nPjt.png)

I am not shure what is happening or what I am doing wrong, so I would very thankful for some help trying to find a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of screenshots, it's better to add the text in code sections directly. And the first screenshot you attached looks broken.